# Nginx always searches index.php in the wrong directory

Tags: nginx, php

I have a web root directory pointing to /var/www/html.

I have several subfolders in /var/www/html where I host different projects. Example: /var/www/html/chatserver

When I try to access http:// MYSERVER.net/chatserver I always have an error because Nginx tries to search for the index.php in the root web folder instead of the actual subfolder.

This is my default server:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name MYSERVER.net www.MYSERVER.net;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl;
server_name MYSERVER.net www.MYSERVER.net;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/MYSERVER.net/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/MYSERVER.net/privkey.pem;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/MYSERVER.net/fullchain.pem;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;

root /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

rewrite ^(.*\.php)(/)(.*)$ $1?file=/$3 last;

location / {
# try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}

location ^~ /.well-known/ {
allow all;
}

location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
fastcgi_index            index.php;
fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
include                  fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
}
```

Comment: Please post your access logs, and if applicable your error logs. Sometimes showing a curl/wget can be helpful.

Comment: I am quite sure adding root directive to the http section would resolve your issue. What happens if you add "root /var/www/html;" to the first server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it's this line:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
```

Try removing the `/` from before `index.php`:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?q=$uri&$args;
```

The `/` is probably causing it to look in the root folder when `$uri` can't be found.

Comment: I have the `/` in my configs and it works. In fact, it's not clear to me how  it works otherwise, unless nginx adds a `/` to the requested location?